# jpa - postgresql unique index annotation definition makes unique constraint instead

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following annotation on the entity class. The database is postgresql. Unfortunately this creates the table with unique constraint, not unique index.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(
        indexes = {
          @Index(name = "MasterT75_unique_idx", columnList = "productdivision, giccode", unique = true)
        }
)
public class MasterT75 extends ModelBaseValidate<MasterT75> {
...
}
```

i've found that, which describes well the difference of unique constraint and index.
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAO8h7BJMX5V1TqzScTx2Nr1jH5iUFG8A071y-g1b_kdzpu9PDw%40mail.gmail.com

but i still don't understand, why hibernate doesn't create index as well (ok, not unique). because there is

```
uniqueConstraints = {}
```

parameter of @Table annnotation. so, if i want to make only unique constraint, i could use the latter one, but if i need index due to performance, i want to have index.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `unique = true`? See also the discussion on this ticket https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8708. Once comment notes: *on postgres, I'd recommend removing the @Index and instead using an explicitly named unique constraint.Postgres automatically creates a unique index for each unique constraint. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-unique.html*

Comment: i need to have unique constraint, to ensure data integrity, but didn't know that postgresql creates an index for the unique constraint. thanks for the link...